# regex php preg_match trying to validate string as sha1

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, sha1

I am trying to validate a string as sha1 with `preg_match()`and seem to be failing.

here is an example string of what I am looking for

```
$str = 'ad209b77134af9c598894a36ed46fc703a0c1e78';
```

here is the pattern I am using trying to get it to match, anyone with enough regex experience able to tell me whats wrong, cause I am horrible with regex.

```
$pattern = '#^[a-f0-9]{40}$#i';
```

then this is how I am using it

```
return (bool) preg_match($pattern, $str));
```

Comment: [Your example matches the input string](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dpOIue)

Comment: you sir are correct, the error was actually due to something entirely different. I had mistyped a variable name and caused it to not get passed into the function, but inside the function I am making to begin with.

Comment: This should be closed as typo/cannot reproduce.

Comment: Just noticed it's 4 years old. But the point stands!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error, its cause earlier in the function I am building, on that one particular rule I called "pattern", "patter" so it was causing the false outcome that was unexpected.